# contact form 7 with new date and new array

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

please I am using wordpress with contact form 7.

I have to add a dropdown menu
to choose a working date to visit.
I used javascript to extract the dates.
When I tried the code without contact form 7, it worked well,
but when I tried to include it the new date object and the new array, it
didn't work.

Here is a simple example just to get what I want to do:

```
<script>
function GetDates(daysToAdd, startDate = new Date()) {
 var aryDates = [];
 var i = 0;
 var dts = 0
 while (dts < daysToAdd) {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  currentDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i);
  if (currentDate.getDay() < 5 || currentDate.getDay() > 5) {
   aryDates.push(DayAsString(currentDate.getDay()) + ", " + currentDate.getDate() + " " + MonthAsString(currentDate.getMonth()) + " " + currentDate.getFullYear());
   dts ++;
  }
  i ++;
 }
 return aryDates;
}

function MonthAsString(monthIndex) {
 var d = new Date();
 var month = new Array();
 month[0] = "يناير";
 month[1] = "فبراير";
 month[2] = "مارس";
 month[3] = "أبريل";
 month[4] = "مايو";
 month[5] = "يونيو";
 month[6] = "يوليو";
 month[7] = "أوت";
 month[8] = "سبتمبر";
 month[9] = "أكتوبر";
 month[10] = "نوفمبر";
 month[11] = "ديسمبر";
 return month[monthIndex];
}

function DayAsString(dayIndex) {
 var weekdays = new Array(7);
 weekdays[0] = "الأحد";
 weekdays[1] = "الإثنين";
 weekdays[2] = "الثلثاء";
 weekdays[3] = "الأربعاء";
 weekdays[4] = "الخميس";
 weekdays[5] = "الجمعة";
 weekdays[6] = "السبت";
 return weekdays[dayIndex];
}
</script>

<h3>المعلومات الشخصية:</h3>
<label> الإسم الكامل (مطلوب):
    [text* f-name] </label>

<label> بريدك الإلكتروني (مطلوب):
    [email* c-email] </label>

<label> رقم الهاتف (مطلوب):
[tel phone] </label>

<h3>خيارات الموعد:</h3>
<label> تاريخ الموعد (مطلوب)
[select date id:dates1]</label>

<script>
var aryDates = GetDates(7);

let dates_list = "";
var combodts = document.getElementById("dates1");
combodts.options.length = 0;
var opt

combodts.add(opt, 0);
for (var i = 0; i < aryDates.length; i++) {
dates_list = dates_list.concat("'", aryDates[i], '\' ');
opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.text = aryDates[i];
opt.value = i;
combodts.add(opt, 0);
}
</script>
<label> الوقت المناسب للموعد (مطلوب)</label>
[radio tyme "الفترة الصباحية" "الفترة المسائية"]

<h3>وصف الحالة</h3>
<label> وصف للحالة (مطلوب)
    [textarea* desc] </label>

[submit "تقديم الطلب"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it
it working now
the problem was with the blanc lines
when i deleted the blanc lines from the js script and put the new date and new array between ()
(new date())
(new array())
the contact form 7 accepted the js code and it working without any problem